# VC++ Memory profiler

Tags: c, memory, profiler

I am looking for a tool to help me minimize the memory allocations inside a C project I'm currently porting.

Mainly, the following information would be useful:

```
1. line of code where memory zone was accessed
2. memory location
3. access mode (read/write)
```

Any form of parsing would be just a bonus, as well as the list of pointers to the indicated memory locations.

Dev tools: Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition

Do you know any software having these features?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1 and 2 you could just

```
void *log_malloc(const char *file, int line, const char *function, size_t size) {

    void *mem = malloc(size);

    /* log or do something with file, line, function, size and mem */

    return mem;
}

#define malloc(size) log_malloc(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, size);
```

And the same for free, calloc, etc.

Comment: three years later: thank you !
Aug 26 '14 was the beginning of a life adventure